# Fundamental group of the $S^2$ with the labeling scheme

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I know that the labeling scheme of $S^2$ is $aa^{-1}$ which should imply the following representation of the fundamental group:

$$\langle a | aa^{-1}=1\rangle$$

but this is not trivial unlike the fundamental group. How do I square this?

Comment: It's probably worth noting that for every element $g$ in any group, it's always true that $gg^{-1}=1$. So your presentation is really just $\langle a \rangle$; i.e., there are no relations in the group you wrote down. Anyway, I'm not quite sure what you mean by your labeling scheme being given by $aa^{-1}$, can you be a bit more precise?

Comment: @kamills yes, the representation I wrote is just $\mathbb{Z}$. I am basically talking about how we obtain $S^2$ from the disc by identifying the boundary. There's a labeling scheme (I don't know how to draw on latex) which describes how the identification is made. Basically, identify two opposite points on the boundary of the disc and then the identification is that you go from on point to the other in both sides (like magnetic fields).

Comment: Gotcha, okay. Well, two things: first, the space I think you're talking about in this comment (taking the disc and identifying antipodal points) actually produces $\mathbb{R}P^2$, the real projective plane. Second, the way to obtain $S^2$ from a disc is to identify all points on the boundary to a single point; this is written $D^2/S^1$.

Comment: If you mean identifying non-antipodal points (i.e. if we consider the disc centered at the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and then we're identifying points on the boundary with the same x-coordinates, like identifying points that would touch if we folded in half along the x-axis), then that does produce $S^2$. But I'm not sure how to write a labeling scheme for this; potentially the labeling scheme is just $1$ since the map $S^1 \to S^1$ that traces $S^1$ on the first half of the domain and then traces $S^1$ backwards on the second half of the domain is nullhomotopic...?

Comment: @kamills I wish I knew how to draw on latex. What you described for the identification of the projective space is when you have the $aa$ labeling scheme. Notice that you get $\mathbb{Z}_2$ as the representation of the fundamental group. The identification which I describe is the one that preserves orientation. Your identification to the point works and so does mine.

Comment: @kamills yes I think we are now talking about the same identification. So the labeling scheme I am talking about is that  if you go counterclockwise on the boundary, you will have to go in $a$ (parallel to the orientation) until you reach the antipodal point and $a^{-1}$  (opposite the orientation) until you get to where you started. So you get $aa^{-1}$ labeling scheme. You will get $aa$ for the projective plane if you try this.

Comment: I follow now. So this labeling scheme is indeed correct. I think the issue in your question comes from misunderstanding how van Kampen's theorem applies to computing fundamental groups from a labeling scheme in this particular case. If you follow the "normal" van Kampen's argument that would compute the fundamental group of, say, the torus, but instead using a disc (using the disc as our 2-sided polygon), you'll get an amalgamated free product of $\mathbb{Z}$ with $0$ over $\mathbb{Z}$, where both copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ are $\langle a \rangle$. This is $0$.

Comment: @kamills I don't understand. Could you elaborate in the answer? Could you also explain why this approach works for the projective plane and not for the sphere?

Answer (score 2):

Note that for a surface $X$ given by a given labeling scheme $a_1^{\epsilon_1}\cdots a_n^{\epsilon_n}$ where each $\epsilon_i = \pm 1$ (not necessarily all presented in order; e.g., $a_1 a_2 a_1^{-1} a_2^{-1}$ is allowed), this is equivalent to obtaining $X$ via the following construction.

Take a wedge of $n$ circles labeled $a_1, \ldots, a_n$, and call this space $X^1$. Then attach $D^2$ to $X^1$ via the map $S^1 \to X^1$ defined as follows: Divide the domain $S^1$ into a number of parts equal to the number of symbols in the labeling scheme, and then for each chunk of the domain $S^1$ we trace the named circle in $X^1$ either forwards or backwards according to the labeling scheme. Call the result $X$.

This wording is complicated, so here are some examples:

For the labeling scheme $a_1 a_2 a_1^{-1} a_2^{-1}$, $X^1$ is a wedge of $2$ circles labeled $a_1$ and $a_2$. We think of the domain $S^1$ as four quarter-circles, and the attaching map says that on the first quarter-circle we trace $a_1$ forwards, then on the second quarter-circle we trace $a_2$ forwards, on the third quarter-circle we trace $a_1$ backwards, and on the fourth quarter-circle we trace $a_2$ backwards. This gives $X$ as the torus.

For the labeling scheme $aa$, $X^1$ is a single circle. The domain $S^1$ is two half-circles, and the attaching map traces $a$ on the first half-circle and then $a$ on the second half-circle, forwards both times. This gives $X$ as $\mathbb{R}P^2$.

To see that this results in a surface equivalent to what you'd expect from the labeling scheme, the point is that the wedge-of-circles is equivalent to drawing a (non-filled-in) polygon where each vertex will be identified, and the "filling in the polygon then gluing the edges according to the labeling scheme" is the same thing as "attaching a disc where the boundary circle traces the labeling scheme's rules." (Also, my notation is suggestive of CW complexes and that's exactly what I'm describing here--the CW decomposition of surfaces.)

For a surface $X$ constructed this way, van Kampen's theorem shows that the fundamental group of $X$ is the group whose generators are the circles $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ and relation given by the labeling scheme. This result you are familiar with since it's what your question is about.

So what's going on with $S^2$? Remember that labeling schemes only give surfaces when they satisfy certain properties, and one of the rules for a labeling scheme such that the above consequence of van Kampen's theorem is true is that it's a fully reduced word in the letters $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ (there are more rules about what orders the letters can come up in, how many times each letter shows up, etc., and perhaps these are part of what a 'labeling scheme' is defined as). So $S^2$'s labeling scheme really should be $1$ if we want to use the result, which would then say that the fundamental group is trivial.

Further, $aa^{-1}$ does not in fact produce $S^2$. Otherwise, this would give $S^2$ as a CW complex with a single 0-cell, a single 1-cell, and a single 2-cell. This has Euler characteristic $1$, but the Euler characteristic of $S^2$ is $2$. This is one example of why your labeling scheme needs to be a reduced word.

This raises an important question, which is "can we write $S^2$ as the result of the above process where we start with a wedge of 0 circles?" After all, my description should work if $n=0$ and if it's going to work for all surfaces, and if the labeling scheme for $S^2$ would be something like "$1$"; i.e., start with no circles. The answer is yes: a wedge of zero circles is a single point (because a wedge sum of circles is the same thing as taking the one-point space and then adding copies of $D^1$ according to the constant attaching map $S^0 \to \{ * \}$), so $X^1$ is the one-point space, and then attach $D^2$ to this via the constant map $S^1 \to \{ * \}$; this gives $S^2$.

The other consideration worth mentioning is that if you do start with $X^1 = S^1$ and attach via $aa^{-1}$, we see that this attaching map is nullhomotopic ($a$ can be thought of as a generator for the fundamental group of $X^1$, and $aa^{-1}$ is the group identity in $\pi_1(X^1)$). And it's a fact of adjunction spaces that the homotopy type of the attaching map is all that matters. So, what do you get if you attach a $2$-cell to $S^1$ via a constant map? This is the space $S^1 \vee S^2$.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I think I should read more about van Kampen's application on CW complexes.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but could you refer to me where I can read more about the rules on the labeling schemes? I understand the description you gave with CW complexes and they are the exact same thing that I am describing but I don't remember seeing anything like it. 

The general result that I have been using is that if I have a space $X$ and the I attach a 2-cell to it to get $Y$, then the inclusion $\iota: X \rightarrow Y $ induces surjection on the fundamental group with the kernel generated by the "attaching maps."

Comment: @asktksa - I fixed some errors. Actually, the issue is that this construction doesn't work for the labeling scheme $aa^{-1}$--if it does, it would imply the Euler characteristic of $S^2$ is $1$. The "rules" for labeling schemes producing surfaces are essentially what prevent this from happening -- a labeling scheme fitting the rules is a space that can be obtained by attaching a single 2-cell to a wedge of circles. (If $S^2$ is to have a single circle as its 1-skeleton, it requires 2 2-cells attached.) As for the rules...

Comment: I don't know of a reference where to find them, but I learned them during the classification of compact connected surfaces. Some of the rules are: words must be fully reduced, every letter you use must appear exactly twice, either as a "twisted pair" ($a$ appearing twice in the word) or an "oriented pair" ($a$ appearing once, $a^{-1}$ appearing once), oriented pairs are interlaced with other oriented pairs (e.g. like the torus). I think these are the only relevant rules for labeling schemes; the other "rules" are more like constructions that occur during the classification theorem.